# Proof of $A \to A^{-1}$ continuous where A $\in$ invertible linear operators on $R^n$

Tags: linear-transformations

The proof of captioned theory in baby rudin 9.8 introduced equation $B^{-1} - A^{-1} = B^{-1}(A-B)A^{-1}$.
I can understand the equation, but what surprise me is that how author come up to this special equation?
While I can not think of this equation, when I come to prove this theory by myself.
Any guidance author is following to come up this equation or simply coincidence?

Comment: $\frac 1 x-\frac 1y =\frac 1  x (y-x)\frac  1y$. Doesn't this suggest the equation used by Rudin?

Comment: This seems a nice hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to consider the context for why the author is even writing this equation down. We assume that $A^{-1}=B^{-1},$ and we would like to demonstrate that $A=B,$ as this would demonstrate that this map is *injective.* In order to facilitate this, we may use the properties of linear operators, specifically, that linear combinations of linear operators are again, linear operators:
$$A^{-1}=B^{-1}\iff A^{-1}-B^{-1}=0.$$
The author knows **the desired result is** $$B-A=0 \iff A=B,$$ and so they used the properties of invertible matrices to get
$$A(A^{-1}-B^{-1})=1-AB^{-1},$$
upon seeing this, they almost surely realized that multiplying on the right by $B$ yield the desired result:
$$A(A^{-1}-B^{-1})B=(1-AB^{-1})B=B-A,$$
and by assumption that $A^{-1}-B^{-1}=0$ we get
$$A(A^{-1}-B^{-1})B=A(0)B=B-A=0.$$

I can't speak to what Rudin actually did to figure this out, but I hope this clarifies the thought process of how one might arrive at this on their own.